# Converting an observable's property in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have an `observableArray` of records which I bind using a `template` binding. This works fine. As I want to keep track of the changes of each of the records, the `observableArray` consists of `observable`s. This works, too.

What I now want is to convert some of the properties of each record (i.e. of each `observable`) to a different type.

How should I proceed?

Usually, I could use a `computed`, but in this case I can not add a single `computed` observable to the array, as I need multiple of them.

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a view model wrapping each item of the observableArray. And this view model can then contain a *computed* property.

```
var ItemViewModel = function (value) {
    this.value = ko.observable(value);
    this.computedValue = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.value() * 2;        
    }, this);    
};

var ViewModel = function (list) {
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray([]);                
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(list, function (value) {
         self.list.push(new ItemViewModel(value)); 
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([1,2,3]));


<ul data-bind="foreach: list">
<li data-bind="text: computedValue"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function to your view model that takes a parameter which is the item from the observable array. The binding will run the function inside of a `dependentObservable`, so any observables that have their value accessed will create a dependency.

So, for example, from [Ryan Niemeyer's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2pB9Y/), you can have the following markup:

```
type "one", "two", or "three": <input data-bind="value: text" /> 
<hr />
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: items }"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name, visible: viewModel.shouldThisBeVisible(name)"></li>
</script>​
```

.. with the view model:

```
var viewModel = {
    text: ko.observable("one"),
    items: [{name: "one"}, {name: "two"}, {name: "three"}],
};

viewModel.shouldThisBeVisible = function(name) {
    return this.text() === name;
}.bind(viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

The crucial bit is where the function takes the parameter of `'name'`. In your case, this would be an item from your observable array.

Hope this helps.